# Using Ajax call to place several custom markers on Google Map

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an Ajax function that gets an array of markers data from the database and displays it on a Google Map. I was sucessful at getting one marker to display however i placed the ajax function on a button click event. The event fires sucessfully without any errors.

The data is returned in the form of json object. The markers are not getting drawn to the map. Under is the code:

**Ajax Function**

```
  $('#getCitizens').click(function(){

        var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.670044,-61.515305),
                         zoom: 16,
                         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);     


        var citizens = (function(){         
                        var citizens = null;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        async : false,
                        global: 'false',
                        url: 'getListOfMarkers.htm',
                        headers : {Accept : 'application/json'},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            citizens = data;
                        }               
                    });
                    return citizens;            
                  })();          

              for(var i= 0; i< citizens.length;i++){

                  console.log(citizens[i].name +' | '+citizens[i].socialSecurityNumber +' | '+citizens[i].latlng);

                  var markerType = citizens[i].citizenType


                  if(markerType = 2){
                      var citizen_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('resources/icons/a_new.ico',new google.maps.Size(100,106),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(50,50));
                  }else if(markerType = 3){
                      var b_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('resources/icons/b_new.ico',new google.maps.Size(100,106),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(50,50));

                  }else if(markerType = 4){
                      var citizen_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('resources/icons/c_new.ico',new google.maps.Size(100,106),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(50,50));
                  }


              var citizenPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(citizens[i].latlng);
              var citizenName = citizens[i].name;
              var citizenMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: citizenPosition,
                  map:map,
                  icon:citizen_icon,
                  title:citizenName

              });

          }


     })
```

**JSON DATA**

```
{"name":"Damien Edwards","latlng":"10.67023300000000,-61.51530500000000","socialSecurityNumber":194302025,"citizenType":3},

{"name":"Raj Hassen","latlng":"10.67030000000000,-61.51530500000000","socialSecurityNumber":198501011,"citizenType":2},

{"name":"Richard Gibbs","latlng":"10.670044,-61.515305","socialSecurityNumber":198501012,"citizenType":2},

{"name":"Sylvester Macintosh","latlng":"10.670044,-61.515305","socialSecurityNumber":1985010122,"citizenType":3},

{"name":"Howard Bugario","latlng":"10.670044,-61.515305","socialSecurityNumber":1985121244,"citizenType":4},

{"name":"Lawerence Figaro","latlng":"10.670044,-61.515305","socialSecurityNumber":1985121245,"citizenType":4},

{"name":"Jessie Small","latlng":"10.670044,-61.515305","socialSecurityNumber":1999020214,"citizenType":3}]

;
```

Comment: Some testing showed that latlng is returning Latlng Position - (NaN, NaN) i think i passed it in as one varible i need think i need to separate them and pass two separate  parameters one for lat and one for lng into var citizenPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(citizens[i].latlng);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite heroic attempts to establish `citizens`, the asynchronicity of `$.ajax()` dictates that it will always be `null` at the time the `for` loop executes.

Try this :

```
$('#getCitizens').on('click', function() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.670044, -61.515305),
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);     
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async : true,
        global: 'false',
        url: 'getListOfMarkers.htm',
        headers : {Accept: 'application/json'},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(citizens) {
        var markerSrcs = [
            null,
            null,
            'resources/icons/a_new.ico',
            'resources/icons/b_new.ico',
            'resources/icons/c_new.ico'
        ];
        $.each(citizens, function(i, c) {
            console.log(c.name + ' | ' + c.socialSecurityNumber + ' | ' + c.latln);
            var src = markerSrcs[c.citizenType];
            if(src) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(c.lat, c.lng),
                    map: map,
                    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( src, new google.maps.Size(100, 106), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(50, 50) ),
                    title: c.name
              });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I can't see why you should need to create a new map each time new citizen markers are created. It's more typical to create one map and reuse it. To do so you would need to keep a reference to the markers (in an array) so they can be removed before adding new ones.

Comment: Can you explain how you select the icons at var markerSrcs = [
             null,
             null,
             'resources/icons/criminal_new.ico',
             'resources/icons/victim_new.ico',
             'resources/icons/suspect_new.ico'
         ];

Comment: the icons get selected based on a value of the citizen type being 2,3,4 you code works thou but how ? I never user jquery like that before i mean i have seen developers used it

Comment: my code works as well except for the fact that i create the new map each time as you rightfully indicated

Comment: also citizens is not null at the time of execution it gets executed the issues was resolved by passing the lat long parameters like i indicated in my answer above

Comment: dev_darin, that way you avoid the rather clumsy if/else if/else if structure by simply indexing into the array, which is made possible by `citizen.citizenType` being an integer. The two nulls at [0] and [1] are present to force the first actual src url into position [2].

Comment: so if other citizenTypes are added lets say one with id 1 then i remove one of the nulls and if lets say one with 6 is added i add two nulls after the 4th element in the array?

Comment: "also citizens is not null " .... Whoops I didn't notice, you're using `asynch:false` which is a no-no as it won't work in all browsers. If you change `asynch:true` (or just delete the option to give default behaviour) then you will find that what I said is correct.

Comment: ohhhh waw you like a guru at this lol. can i keep in touch with you mr. please give me your email addy or somthing plz lol

Comment: "so if other citizenTypes are added ...", yes, just make sure there's an entry in the right position in `markerSrcs` for every `.citizenType` the server is likely to return.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29459/discussion-between-dev-darin-and-beetroot-beetroot)

Comment: dev_darin, there are plenty of guys here who are at least as experienced as me. As long as you ask clear well phrased questions, then you will generally attract an answer - sometimes with astonishing speed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was really related at this point :

```
var citizenPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(citizens[i].latlng);
```

google.maps.LatLng() accepts two parameters one for lat and one for lng i passed only one parameter which was concatenated to form latlng. The isses was resolved by:

```
var citizenPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(citizens[i].lat, citizens[i].lng);
```

Answer (score -1):

AJAX is asynchronous so you can't return the response ( `citizens`) from a function the way you are doing , it will be still `null`.

The easiest is to consume the data within the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
   /* async: false,*/   /* don't use async:false , it is deprecated and bad practice*/
    global: 'false',
    url: 'getListOfMarkers.htm',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var citizens = data;
        /* run all marker code here*/
        for (var i = 0; i < citizens.length; i++) {.......
        }
});
```

Also am curious about url being `.htm` ,is not common for sending json

Comment: will try this .htm is what i have in the @RequestParam its a SpringMVC app it works for me thou